# How to pass generic KeyValuePair<Tkey,TValue> to a WebMethod?

Tags: web-services, generics, key-value

```
 [WebMethod]
public void Test(KeyValuePair<string,string> details)
{        
}
```

I have defined the above web-method.

The KeyValuePair is defined in 
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic

how can i add it to my wsdl auto-generated file? 
i have to define this type because otherwise i get an empty definition in the wsdl file:

```
<s:complexType name="KeyValuePairOfStringString" />
```

Comment: +1 - This drives me up the wall - I hope someone's got a decent solution.

Answer (score 2):

For that particular problem, I'd recommend changing the signature to

```
public void Test(string key, string value)
```

as I've never got web services to play nicely with generics. If you have any other methods with similar problems, you can use the auto-generated proxy classes, or pass things in as objects and cast them back within the web method.

Comment: That doesn't really work since my goal is to pass a List<KeyValuePair>
actualy i started with dicitonary, and then downgraded to a list..
the list actualy work, but the problem stays with the KeyValuePair<String,String> which isn't being parsed correctly by the wsdl - my guess is because i am missing the definiton of it from 
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic
the problem is - that this link seems to be broken , and also i dont know how to add it to my webservice - in order the wsdl to use it to figure out what KeyValuePairOfStringString really means.

Comment: my temporary solution was to manually create a class called KeyValuePairOfStringString , but then i also need KeyValuePairOfStringLong and KeyValuePairOfSomeEnumSomeOtherClass 

which is quite ugly!!! :(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help - be sure to revisit this post and let us know if you find a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue too. Looks like i will have to create a specific class(es) for now.